# What causes ExtAudioFileRead to make ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize negative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, aac, audiobufferlist, extaudiofileread

The problem occurs when I often stop and start audio playback and seek a lot back and forth in an AAC audio file through an `ExtAudioFileRef` object. In few cases, this strange behaviour is shown by `ExtAudioFileRead`:

Sometimes it assigns these numbers to the `mDataByteSize` of the only `AudioBuffer` of the `AudioBufferList`:

```
-51604480
-51227648
-51350528
-51440640
-51240960
```

In hex, these numbers have the pattern `0xFC....00`.

The code:

```
status = ExtAudioFileRead(_file, &numberFramesRead, ioData);

printf("s=%li d=%p d.nb=%li, d.b.d=%p, d.b.dbs=%li, d.b.nc=%li\n", status, ioData, ioData->mNumberBuffers, ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize, ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels);
```

Output:

```
s=0 d=0x16668bd0 d.nb=1, d.b.d=0x30de000, d.b.dbs=1024, d.b.nc=2 // good (usual)
s=0 d=0x16668bd0 d.nb=1, d.b.d=0x30de000, d.b.dbs=-51240960, d.b.nc=2 // misbehaving
```

The problem occurs on an iPhone 4S on iOS 7. I could not reproduce the problem in the Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when concurrently calling `ExtAudioFileRead()` and `ExtAudioFileSeek()` for the same `ExtAudioFileRef` from two different threads/queues.

The read function was called directly from the `AURenderCallback`, so it was executed on AudioUnit's real-time thread while the seek was done on my own serial queue.

I've modified the code of the render callback to also dispatch_sync() to the same serial queue to which the seek gets dispatched. That solved the problem.